# Return a tuple with hasSuffix

Tags: swift

I'm learning swift from a book and I come across a challenge that I don't know how to solve.

Here is the challenge: Write a function called `siftBeans(fromGroceryList:)` that takes a grocery list (as an array of strings) and “sifts out” the beans from the other groceries. The function should take one argument that has a parameter name called list, and it should return a named tuple of the type `(beans: [String], otherGroceries: [String])`.

Here is an example of how you should be able to call your function and what the result should be:

```
let result = siftBeans(fromGroceryList: ["green beans",
                                         "milk",
                                         "black beans",
                                         "pinto beans",
                                         "apples"])

result.beans == ["green beans", "black beans", "pinto beans"] // true
result.otherGroceries == ["milk", "apples"] // true
```

*Hint: You may need to use a function on the String type called hasSuffix(_:).*

Comment: Do you know how to use `filter` on an `Array`?

Comment: Yes I know,  here is how I did it in another way.

let list = ["green beans", "milk", "black beans", "pinto beans", "apples"]

var beans:[String] = []
var otherGroceries:[String] = []

func siftBeans(fromGroceryList: [String])
{
    for i in fromGroceryList
    {
        if i.hasSuffix("beans")
        {
            beans.append(i)
        }
        else
        {
           otherGroceries.append(i)
        }
    }
    
}

siftBeans(fromGroceryList: list)
print(beans)
print(otherGroceries)

Comment: OK, good that you have had a go. I'll put an answer now of how I would do it. I didn't want to answer without you having a go and doing it yourself :D

Comment: thank you!  I also think it's good to try first by yourself even if you fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would write the function.

```
func siftBeans(groceries: [String]) -> (beans: [String], otherGroceries: [String]) {
    return (
        groceries.filter { $0.hasSuffix("beans") },
        groceries.filter { !$0.hasSuffix("beans") }
    )
}
```

The filter function uses the `hasSuffix` to determine if the items should be included. So I just run it twice, once to get all the `...beans` items and one to get the rest of the items.

It does iterate the array twice but that is not such a big deal. I actually have a function that does a `filterInOut` on an array that does this for me for any array.

**EDIT**

I wanted to improve on this and see if I could provide a better generic alternative.

So I came up with this...

```
extension Collection {
    func separated(_ divisor: (Iterator.Element) -> (Bool)) -> (in: [Iterator.Element], out: [Iterator.Element]) {
        return reduce((in: [], out: [])) {
            divisor($1) ? ($0.in + [$1], $0.out) : ($0.in, $0.out + [$1])
        }
    }
}
```

It's an extension on `Collection` so can be used on any type of collection. It takes a closure that returns a `Bool`. The result is a tuple `(in: [], out: [])` that uses the closure to filter items either way.

It can be used like this...

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
array.separated { $0 % 2 == 0 } // ([2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 3, 5, 7])
```

Or, in your use case...

```
let array = ["green beans", "milk", "black beans", "pinto beans", "apples"]
array.separated { $0.hasSuffix("beans") } // (["green beans", "black beans", "pinto beans"], ["milk", "apples"])
```

Hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

tuple items can have names like function parameters. this is the function you are looking for

```
func siftBeans(from groceryList: [String]) -> (beans: [String], otherGroceries: [String]) {
    var beans = [String]()
    var otherGroceries = [String]()
    groceryList.forEach { (grocery) in
        grocery.hasSuffix("beans") ? beans.append(grocery) : otherGroceries.append(grocery)
    }
    return (beans , otherGroceries)
}
```

Comment: "This is the function you are looking for"... no, that is the way that you have written a function that does what is asked. There a many many millions of ways of writing it. :)

Comment: @Fogmeister sure there are millions of ways to do the same thing. what i meant is how i would implement this to show someone usage of forEach and tuple naming.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine a single `filter` operation with `Set.substracting` so you only need to call `filter` once on the original array instead of calling it twice (once for the elements having the suffix and once for the elements not having it).

```
func filterBeans(groceryList: [String])->(beans: [String], otherGroceries: [String]){
    let beans = groceryList.filter({$0.hasSuffix("beans")})
    let otherGroceries = Array(Set(groceryList).subtracting(beans))
    return (beans, otherGroceries)
}
```

Of course for this to work, the input `groceryList` needs to have only unique elements (otherwise creating the intermediate `Set` will get rid of the duplicates).

Comment: using Set for subtracting will lose order of array. so  the code:
result.otherGroceries == ["milk", "apples"] will be false sometimes

Comment: I guess that was just an example from OP showing the expected output, but you are right, the ordering is not preserved.